# Warning: Unavailable Version of Java Requested

Tags: security, java, warning

We are updating client computers to JRE 1.7 but a partner Web application has a mention of the older java version in its applet HTML tags (java_version=1.6*). Because of this mention, the applet loading is preceded by the warning "Unavailable Version of Java Requested", which asks permissions to run the applet with the latest Java version. If the user clicks Yes, the application works without any issues until the applet disappears from the Java cache.

As we always have only one Java version on our computers, showing these irritating popups does not make any sense for our users and we want to suppress them.

We played with different policies available in deployment.properties, like deployment.insecure.jres=Always and found nothing that allows suppressing this warning.

The selected preference to run this particular applet with the latest version of JRE is store in the Java cache for the life or the applet in the cache. So it is not manageable either.

Is there any policies or settings to prevent these warning from displaying?
Except of making a silly vbs to automatically click Yes on the popup?

Comment: Contact the partner and ask them, perhaps much less than politely, to fix their web page?

Comment: Already done, but the partner is a very big company with many thousands of customers and very slow to apply changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is found in Java 7.40 via Deployment Rule Sets.